# Firefox forcing text on same line

Tags: html, css, firefox, xhtml

I have a piece of HTML and CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main *{
        position:absolute;
    }
</style>

<div id="main">
    <div class="cards_description">
        Business
        <br />
        Cards!
    </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox. Even though there is a line break. The text is on the same line

> Business Cards!

instead of

> Business
>
> Cards!

I do not have this issue in chrome. Is there some CSS that will correct this issue?

I am on Firefox version 17.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `<p>` tag, Like: `<p>Business <br />Cards!</p>`

Comment: Tested it and it does work in Firefox when you wrap the text with a `<p>` tag.

Comment: Paragraphs are block level elements by default, he wont need the line break since the elements will occupy all available space.

Comment: It seems to work if I wrap it anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @John you really should wrap it in the <p> tag though since it is the proper HTML tag for paragraphs: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    ...
    .cards_description span {
        display : block;
    }
    ...
</style>

<div id="main">
    <div class="cards_description">
        <span>Business</span> <span>Cards!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```